# quadratic system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a quadratic system of differential equations. I will be thankful if anyone can help me in this regards

The equation is of the form

> $$x'=a_1x^2+b_1y^2+a_1b_1xy$$
>
> $$y'=a_2x^2+b_2y^2+a_2b_2xy$$

Comment: Are you sure you want the same coefficients in the expressions for $x'$ and $y'$?  As written, we must have $x' = y'$. . .

Comment: Thank you, It was a mistake from myside